# flex BlazeDS spring hibernate

Tags: apache-flex, hibernate, spring, blazeds

I try to start Java EE, so after studying the frameworks available for this architecture, i choose to use the following one: Flex, BlazeDS, Spring, Hibernate, mysql. i will work with eclipse or STS.

The problem is that, after trying different project all over web tutorial, i wasn't able to create an architecture that gather all the last versions off technologies i choose.

**SO, can someone send me a links which refer a tutorial where it's preferable that the source code is available to download, and it gives the explanation about what is done.**

Comment: I voted to close; as I'm unsure what information you're asking for.  Please feel free to edit your question to be more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

description: http://sebastien-arbogast.com/2009/11/07/spring-flex-blazeds-full-stack-is-back/
source: https://github.com/sarbogast/todolist-spring

Answer (score 1):

Check out my [Flex 4, Hibernate 3, and Spring 3 Integration Refcard](http://www.jamesward.com/2010/06/14/flex-4-hibernate-3-and-spring-3-integration/).